# Django and Chart.js Not Rendering Graph Correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, chart.js

So I spent the weekend testing and searching SO and finally got Django and Chart.js working.  Kind of.  It renders the graph but the data is not correct.  When I loop through the object, the results are not what I would expect.  Maybe I'm blind from staring at this all weekend.  Would appreciate any pointers.

Here are my views...

```
class ChartView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Books/chart.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qs1 = Class.objects.filter(id__in=self.request.user.userprofile.class.all()).order_by('id')
        qs2 = Books.objects.filter(class__in=self.request.user.userprofile.books.all()).distinct()
        context['qs1'] = qs1
        context['qs2'] = qs2
        return context

class ChartData(LoginRequiredMixin,APIView):
    model = Books
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs_count = Books.objects.filter(class__in=self.request.user.userprofile.class.all()).count()
        labels = []
        default_items = []
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Here's my HTML with the Javascript...

```
{% extends 'base5.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="box6">
          <h1 class="title">Number of Books By Class</h1>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<div>

<script>
var endpoint = '{% url "Books:chart_data" %}'
var defaultData = [];
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [{% for i in qs1 %}{{ i.id }},{% endfor %}],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "# of Books",
                     data: [{% for j in qs2 %}
                              {{ j.id }},
                            {% endfor %}],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }
        })
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Here are the models.

```
class Books(models.Model):

    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=264,unique=False)
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='classes')

class Class(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="teacher_name")
```

I feel like my looping logic in qs2 is where the problem is.  It is not properly looping through qs2, as it is returning results, but not the proper ones.  I'm only trying to get the books out of the the user that match the class, and it's not working.  Also, I can only get the "ID" to display on the graph, not the actual foreign key name.  I can't figure out how to get the actual foreign key name to display either.  Appreciate any help or pointers as to what I'm doing incorrectly.  I'm so close!

Comment: Are the dictionary keys for "# of books" and "foreign key" both equal to "ID"?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.  I have updated the code to include my models.

Comment: Try displaying the entire object "{{i}}" or "{{j}}" to see what data the object holds. Is the data you need inside of the object?

Comment: Yes.  That's the odd thing.  I actually included a print statement, and it correctly identifies 4 items in the object.  But when I loop through, I get a total of 8.  That's what's so maddening.  If I only have two different books, it works fine.  When I add the third book, the graph picks up the book even though the class is not associated with the user.  I'm trying to show the books by class.  Once I get beyond two, it doesn't work right.

Comment: Hi @SteveSmith, there is couple issues with the code, but let's get this straight, you want the number of `Books` corresponding the each `Class` to be displayed in the chart, **all the Books**

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I'm trying to limit the display based on what is in the userprofile so that the user can only see the books that are associated with the classes for his profile.  Hence the filtering I've done on the self.request.user.userprofile.class.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I use Postgresql.

Comment: I am trying to show a bar chart showing the number of book by class.  I'm trying to loop through and get the number of books with a separate bar for each class showing the total if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    qs1 = Class.objects.filter(id__in=self.request.user.userprofile.class.all()).order_by('id')        
    class_names = [ cls.class_name for cls in qs1]
    books_count = [ Books.objects.filter(class=cls).count() for cls in qs1 ]
    context['qs1'] = class_names
    context['qs2'] = books_count
    return context
```

Here i want both the `Class` and `Books` queryset to be ordered by class because the order is crucial. Here in the context i inject the `Class` names and `Books` count directly in the context.

Use This srcipt in the `template`:

```
<script>
        var labels = "{{ qs1 }}";
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: Array.from(labels),
                datasets: [{
                    label: "# of Books",
                     data: [{% for j in qs2 %}
                              {{ j }},
                            {% endfor %}],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }
        })
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
</script>
```

There is no need for ajax request you already got the data from the `context`

I hope this will work.

Comment: Great news!  The suggestions you made regarding the filter did the trick!!!!  Thank you so much!!!  I tried the Class name suggestions for qs1, and class_name doesn't seem to be coming through...I can only get the ID number....Can't get the class name....

Comment: Class was just an example, I am using a different name in my code.  And as far as class_name, yes, I can't get anything other than ID to come through.  Can't figure out how to get the name to come through instead.

Comment: Yusef, after further testing, your filter suggestions aren't quite working.  Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't.  I am wondering if perhaps the fact that I have class defined as a manytomanyfield in my userprofile model is complicating things?

Comment: I've been testing it.  I got past all errors and now I just get a blank screen.  Can't get data to come through.  Syntax doesn't seem to be quite right.

Comment: No that still isn't working.  Nothing comes through.  Blank screen again.

Comment: Ok, but still there is no need for the ajax request. Now is there any errors in the borwser's console, print the `context` in the server's console to see `class_names` and `books_count`.

Comment: So I added the information to print and the class_names are coming through.  The books_count is coming through as well, but it seems to be off.

Comment: Ok, What about browser console errors, is there any?

Comment: Hmm ok, in the script try `var labels = [{% for i in qs1 %}{{ i }},{% endfor %}]` and `console.log` it, the same for `qs2`.

Comment: Are you able to go to chat in 15 mins?

Comment: @SteveSmith Ok of course [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173766/discussion-between-yusef-bh-and-steve-smith)

Answer (score 2):

After working all day with Yusef BH, came to the following solution regarding rendering the data correctly.  Of note is that the labels are still not coming through.  I have opened up a separate SO issue for the labels.  Here is the code that allowed me to display the items correctly on the graph.

My HTML

```
{% extends 'base5.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="box6">
          <h1 class="title">Number of Books By Author</h1>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<div>

  <script>
  var endpoint = '{% url "Books:chart_data" %}'
  var defaultData = [];
  var labels = [];
  array = {{ procedures3 }}
  $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      url: endpoint,
      success: function(data){
          defaultData = data.default
          var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'bar',
              data: {
                  labels: [{% for i in book %}{{ i.id }},{% endfor %}],
                  datasets: [{
                      label: "# of Procedures",
                      data: [{% for j in book_count %}
                               {{ j }},
                             {% endfor %}],
                      backgroundColor: [
                          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                      ],
                      borderColor: [
                          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 1
                  }]
              }
          })
      },
      error: function(error_data){
          console.log("error")
          console.log(error_data)
      },
  })
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

Views.py

ChartView

```
class ChartData(LoginRequiredMixin,APIView):
    model = Author
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        default_items = []
        labels = []
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

The ChartView

```
class ChartView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView): template_name = 'Book/chart.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ChartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    book = Author.objects.filter(id__in=self.request.user.userprofile.author.all()).order_by('id')
    books_count = [ Book.objects.filter(author=cls).count() for cls in book ]
    context['book'] = book
    context['book_count'] = books_count
    return context
```